Calculating distance between point and polygon center using ArcGIS Pro
I am using ArcGIS Pro.
I have a map of several counties with lots of different points for air monitors. I also have the center of each county marked with a point. I want to calculate the distance between the monitors and the center of its county. However, when I use the Near tool, it just does the distance between the monitors and whatever county center is closest.
Is there a way I can specify?

The picture upload should be working again: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/402185/image-uploading-isnt-working

You can use the "Generate Near Table (Analysis)" tool with the "Find only closest feature" parameter unchecked.    The output will be a table of all feature <> feature distances, so to minimise processing, you can set a maximum distance or number of matches.
Assuming you have a "county" name or ID attribute in both county center and monitor points (if you don't, do a spatial join to attach county attribute to points). You can then join county center and monitor points to the output table by objectid and filter to show only distances where county center "county" name/ID equals the monitor point "county" name/ID.

@AmberShuman did this answer your question? If so, consider accepting it or providing feedback so it can be improved.
